# Unable to join docker swarm using Oracle Cloud VMs connected to the same VCN

Tags: docker-swarm, iptables, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to use two compute instances in Oracle cloud as nodes in a tiny Docker Swarm (using Oracle provided Ubuntu 20.04 as base system). The problem is, that I can't seem to make a connection between the two. Node1 and Node2 have IPs 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3, respectively. Obviously, they are connected to the same virtual cloud network and using `arp -a` for example shows the IP of the other node (from whichever I execute the command), so they truly are on the same network.

The problem is, that even though arp sees the other node, ping doesn't work, I get 100% package loss. This in itself wouldn't bother me much, but after issuing `docker swarm init` on Node1 and `docker swarm join <token> 10.0.0.2:2377`, I get a timeout error and no connection is established.

I tried to open up all all the needed ports (TCP 2377, TCP UDP 7946, UDP 4789) in iptables by editing the /etc/iptables/rules.v4, but no luck. Basically this is what I appended to the INPUT parts:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2377 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4789 -j ACCEPT
```

Nonetheless, no luck. I rebooted the system as well, but still no joy. As far as I'm concerned I did everything necessary to be able to join a swarm, but for some reason it doesn't work. Interestingly, on a non-VM Gentoo install the iptables ruleset also contains the following:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2376 -j ACCEPT
```

Which is not mentioned in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts) and the manager generated join-token doesn't contain this port.

Could this missing entry be a problem? Or is there some sort of setting I'm missing in the Oracle Cloud network setup (like client isolation, etc)?
Could somebody give some suggestions on how to debug this if it is indeed a network issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicions got confirmed: all traffic between clients is blocked by default in Oracle cloud. The solution is to add rules for the mentioned ports to the security list of the VCN the VMs are connected to. After that everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I stumbled over the same issue. What a shame! No documents never mentioned port **2376**.

Comment: I mean *ever mentioned* :)